# OSx, Right align text in NSTable using NSCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an `NSTableView`, cell based, with several columns and have the text align set for right in IB and all works. Looking at expanding, so decided to use `NSCell` to customize the printing in the table columns. I can change the font color and the font size without issues, but I can not seam to get the text to right justify in the cell. I have tried many different things and nothing seams to work. Hope someone has an idea that will work.

Tried the following:

```
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
 [paraStyle setAlignment: NSRightTextAlign];
 NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributedName: paraStyle, NSFontAttributedName: [NSFont systemFontOfSize: 13]};
 myPoint.x = cellFrame.origin.x;
 myPoint.y = cellFrame.origin.y;
 [myString drawAtPoint: thePoint withAttributes: textAttributes];
```

That does not work. I also tried using an NSAttributedString.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attMyString = [NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: myString];
 [attMyString setAttributes: textAttributes range: NSMakeRange(0, [attMyString lenght])];
 [attMyString drawAtPoint: thePoint];
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Again, I can change the font size and color so everything is linked properly - I just can't right justify.

Thank You.

Comment: thePoint is at the left side of the cell so drawAtPoint will draw on the left side of the cell. Try drawInRect.

Comment: duh! drawInRect is what I needed to do. Sometimes ya can't see the trees through the forest, thanks for responding. If you want credit, put it in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thePoint is at the left side of the cell so drawAtPoint will draw on the left side of the cell. drawInRect will do what you want.